# When designing a simple website toolbar layout in powerpoint office 16, is it possible to animate menu items to expand and collapse upon clicking?

Tags: website-design, animation, microsoft-powerpoint, windows-10

I am designing the layout/look-and-feel of a website in Microsoft PowerPoint (Office 16) on Windows 10.

The website I am designing will have a horizontal toolbar at the top that will allow the user to click on menus and select menu items (just like StackExchange has a horizontal toolbar at the top that allows to click on "Recent Inbox messages" menu or "Recent achievements" menu.). So if you click on Recent Inbox messages >> inbox message # 5, StackExchange will take you directly to that question.

Is it possible to have a horizontal toolbar in PowerPoint with various menus and menu items so that when you click on a menu, powerpoint will animate and expand the menu items associated with what you click on? If the presenter clicks on a menu item, can PowerPoint take you do another slide and back?

Right now I am doing all this manually (slide 1 shows toolbar with menus).  Slide 2 shows one of the menus expanded with its menu items.  Slide 3 shows what happens if you click on one of the menu items.  Then I go back to slide 1. Then slide 4 shows a different menu expanded with its menu items.  Slide 5 shows what happens if you click on one of the menu items from slide 4.

So I am switch back and forth between slides.  I'm wondering if PowerPoint can have links for each  menu item so that it automatically goes to the correct slide without me keeping track of which slide I need to go to next.  Also, a back button would be great, so it takes me back to the previous slide I was on without me needing to remember which slide that was.

A perfectly acceptable answer can be a link to a powerpoint file online somewhere that does exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I don't know how many are using PowerPoint to design websites.

However, you can insert links within slides - either to other slides in the same deck, a different deck, an email, a web site, etc.

Highlight the text, shape, image, etc you want to be the link and then choose `Insert > Hyperlink...` and then select from the options.

The animation is another matter and outside my wheelhouse, but may be one of the reasons PowerPoint is not known as a "web design" tool. While it may be 100% possible, Microsoft application, in general, have a way of making internal complex structures/operations (such as animation) not very well written when exported for different delivery methods. This is true not only for HTML/CSS, but for PDFs as well.